# performing a group by in JSON aggregate

Tags: postgresql

I have table format like this below

| parentid | date | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-03-15' | '18:30' | 35 |
| 2 | '2021-03-17' | '15:30' | 15 |
| 2 | '2021-03-16' | '13:30' | 25 |
| 1 | '2021-03-15' | '10:30' | 45 |

I want the data to be grouped by parentid first and then for each parentit have json. For an example

```
   ParentID         JSON

      1            [
                   {"2021-03-15": [{"10:30:00": 45}, {"18:30:00": 35}]}
                   ]

      2            [
                   {"2021-03-16": [{"13:30:00": 25}]}, 
                   {"2021-03-17": [{"15:30:00": 35}]} 
                   ]
```

i.e group by dates and then time and its corresponding value. I'm using json_aggr and json_build_object but I cant find a way to group the dates.

Comment: What if you have multiple different `date` values for a `parentid`?  And where do the dates `2021-03-02` to `2021-03-14` come from? They are not in the sample data. And why is `2021-03-16` excluded from the output?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the JSON according to the table, also if there multiple dates I want them iterate in the JSON, check patientid 2 JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b9de6e538ae82d61f0db548ad4f65da4)

It is not clear to me, why you want to create `{"2021-03-15": [{"10:30:00": 45}, {"18:30:00": 35}]}` instead of `{"2021-03-15": {"10:30:00": 45, "18:30:00": 35}}`. The array seems not necessary for me.

Same for `[{"2021-03-16": [{"13:30:00": 25}]}, {"2021-03-17": [{"15:30:00": 35}]}]` instead of `{"2021-03-16": {...}, "2021-03-17": {...}}`.

However you requested result can be achieved by this query:

```
SELECT
    parentid,
    json_agg(new_object)                          -- 4
FROM (
    SELECT
        parentid,
        "date",
        json_build_object("date",                 -- 3
            json_agg(                             -- 2
                json_build_object("time", value)  -- 1
            )
        ) as new_object
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY parentid, "date"
) s
GROUP BY parentid
```

1. Create your time object
2. Aggregate the time objects into an array (using `GROUP BY`)
3. Create the date object with the new array
4. Aggregate all date objects into an array (using a second `GROUP BY`)

Comment: Only reason I want the brackets are because im trying merge the json to another json using ||, but for some reason when I merge it only retrieves a single child level key value pair. Do you know any reason why its happening

Answer (score 1):

You need to two-stop aggregation. First aggregate the times by parentid and date. Then  aggregate those JSON values per parentid:

```
select parentid, 
       jsonb_object_agg("date", times)
from (       
  select parentid, 
         "date"::text as "date", 
         jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object("time"::text, value)) as times
  from the_table 
  group by parentid, "date"
) t
group by parentid  
;
```